# Cannot inject JNDI entry with "/" in its name into String property of spring bean using @Value

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, naming-conventions, jndi

I'm trying to inject a JNDI entry from my JBoss's configuration file into a `String` property of my Spring bean using `@Value`.

It works when my JNDI entry's name doesn't have a forward slash in its name, like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1">
    <bindings>
        <simple name="urlBestanden" value="C:\Users\henrique.ordine\Documents"/>
```

When I do include a forward slash (`<simple name="url/bestanden" value="C:\Users\henrique.ordine\Documents"/>`) it fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value [org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext@a56b0b] from source type [NamingContext] to target type [String]
```

How come?

This is how my property is annotated:

```
@Value("#{environment.url/bestanden}") private String baseFilePath;
```

Comment: Can you show a full stack trace ? I suspect it is one of the Spring PropertyEditors not parsing the JNDI name as you'd expect. It's probably one of the PropertyEditor classes here, which you can then debug:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html (Table 8.2. Built-in PropertyEditors)

Comment: I'd stick a break point in PropertySourcesPropertyResolver on this line:

if (!this.conversionService.canConvert(valueType, targetValueType)) {

and see what it's up to ?

Do you need to prefix your string with something like this "java:/" ? That is implied by this [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/25384-jndi-datasource-configuration-problem-again)